# Team Foundation Server unable to build. Missing libraries or components?

Tags: vb.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to create a build using TFS and a build server.  This is my first attempt with the build server and it is not going well!!

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012.
The project is written in VB.Net and uses a fair number of references.  When I build the project on my dev machine I have no issues; but then I have Outlook 2013 installed and all the various required components.

When I send the project off to the build server I am getting many warnings about missing types that pertain to outlook plus a couple of mystery library's.
I cannot put outlook on the build server; so how do I resolve this problem?

here are some of the messages.
    er.vb (45): Type 'Outlook.Recipient' is not defined.
    er.vb (42): Type 'Outlook.NameSpace' is not defined.
    er.vb (39): Type 'Interop.Outlook.Application' is not defined.
    rs.vb (1141): Type 'Interop.Outlook.Attachment' is not defined.
    rs.vb (1144): 'Outlook' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1988): 
Cannot get the file path for type library "2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52" version 2.7. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1988): 
Cannot get the file path for type library "00062fff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 9.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
```

The bottom 2 messages are not Outlook related, frankly I am unsure what it is looking for there?

The final message from the attempted build is:

Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I'm assuming I am receiving this because of the various missing components?
 Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have a number of references that only exist in your GAC or are in your local program files tree.
Open up your project files in a text editor add see if there are.
You need to replace these with lib references from your source tree in one of two ways.

1. **Nuget packages** (recommended). Add packages/dll required
2. **lib folder** (older method). Create a folder in your source tree and drop in the dlls that you require.-

If your update your references and then update your scm. Your build should then be self contained and build.

Installing large software packages on a build agent to fix a dll reference is bad practice and a build agent should be left as clean as possible.
A source tree should contain all links/info to what is needed to build it. (except maybe the .dot net framework)