# Azure error Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure.  I have a ASP.Net solution that I deploy to Azure. Recently, I started getting the error "Azure error Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'" when I push my code to Azure and it builds.  I have no errors when I build and run locally.  Only when I commit and push to Azure.  Anyone have any experience with this?  I wish I had more to provide, but I am not sure what that could be. My project is set for Any CPU, VS 2017, and is a mix of ASP.Net and .Net projects.  This error just started happening and use to work fine.  I do not manage the Azure environment but I do have some access to the pipeline.

Here is the last bit on my build log.  Its quite large but I can post the whole thing, if that would help.

```
2019-01-17T17:21:56.7483883Z   No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4429368Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52" version 2.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4430009Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52" version 2.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4431536Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4affc9a0-5f99-101b-af4e-00aa003f0f07" version 9.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4431938Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4affc9a0-5f99-101b-af4e-00aa003f0f07" version 9.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4436368Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4436922Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4439882Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:57.4440471Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:58.5690796Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
2019-01-17T17:21:58.5691374Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit. [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:58.5783744Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2019-01-17T17:21:58.6375907Z Project "D:\a\1\s\GHApplicationGuide.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj" (8) on node 1 (default targets).
2019-01-17T17:21:58.6376071Z PrepareForBuild:
2019-01-17T17:21:58.6376597Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\".
2019-01-17T17:21:58.7605601Z GenerateBindingRedirects:
2019-01-17T17:21:58.7606057Z   No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8006462Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 8.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8007039Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 8.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8010494Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8011248Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8335534Z CoreResGen:
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8336350Z   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:D:\a\1\s\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.8.1\lib\net40\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Deployment.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\WindowsBase.dll" /compile "My Project\Resources.resx",obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.Resources.resources
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8337865Z   Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.Resources.resources".
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8703202Z GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8704065Z Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8736923Z CoreCompile:
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8738046Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Diagnostics,System.Linq,System.Xml.Linq,System.Threading.Tasks /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict:custom /nowarn:42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022 /optioninfer+ /nostdlib /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /rootnamespace:PrintApplicationGuidePDF /sdkpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2" /highentropyva+ /doc:obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.xml /define:"CONFIG=\"Release\",TRACE=-1,_MyType=\"Console\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.8.1\lib\net40\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Deployment.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll",D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\WindowsBase.dll" /main:PrintApplicationGuidePDF.Module1 /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.Resources.resources /target:exe /utf8output Module1.vb "My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" "My Project\Application.Designer.vb" "My Project\Resources.Designer.vb" "My Project\Settings.Designer.vb" "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.vb"
2019-01-17T17:21:58.8741018Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5718650Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735372Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.8.1\lib\net40\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" to "bin\Release\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735521Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735800Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\NLog.dll" to "bin\Release\NLog.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735841Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.dll" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735928Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.dll" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5735984Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5736038Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Lucene.Net.dll" to "bin\Release\Lucene.Net.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5736243Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.dll" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5736283Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll" to "bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5757263Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5775450Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.pdb" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5776238Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.xml" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5795073Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll.config" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL.dll.config".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5805126Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\NLog.xml" to "bin\Release\NLog.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5805484Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.xml" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5805836Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.8.1\lib\net40\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.xml" to "bin\Release\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5806443Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.pdb" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideDataLayer.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5926801Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.pdb" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5927177Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.xml" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5927392Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Lucene.Net.pdb" to "bin\Release\Lucene.Net.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5927604Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Lucene.Net.xml" to "bin\Release\Lucene.Net.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5927819Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.dll.config" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.UsersGuideUtilities.dll.config".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5928236Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.xml" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5928454Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.xml" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5928649Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.pdb" to "bin\Release\mycompany.gh.p3.DATA.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5928855Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\EntityFramework.xml" to "bin\Release\EntityFramework.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5929038Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\mycompany.gh.p3.ApplicationGuideBL\bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.xml" to "bin\Release\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5950222Z   Creating "D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5972301Z _CopyAppConfigFile:
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5972620Z   Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.exe.config".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5981528Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5981667Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.exe" to "bin\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.exe".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5993676Z   PrintApplicationGuidePDF -> D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\bin\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.exe
2019-01-17T17:21:59.5995953Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.pdb" to "bin\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.pdb".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6001750Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.xml" to "bin\Release\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.xml".
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6034343Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj" (default targets).
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6038955Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\GHApplicationGuide.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6057301Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6058362Z Build FAILED.
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6097615Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6105865Z "D:\a\1\s\GHApplicationGuide.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6106021Z "D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj" (default target) (7) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6106071Z (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6106404Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6106682Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6106905Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6107152Z "D:\a\1\s\GHApplicationGuide.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6107603Z "D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj" (default target) (7) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6107852Z (ResolveComReferences target) -> 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6108127Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52" version 2.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6108541Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4affc9a0-5f99-101b-af4e-00aa003f0f07" version 9.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6108830Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6109239Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6109525Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit. [D:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\DataImportScript.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6109798Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6110709Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6111058Z "D:\a\1\s\GHApplicationGuide.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6111384Z "D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj" (default target) (8) ->
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6111727Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 8.5. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6112103Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 5.3. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [D:\a\1\s\PrintApplicationGuidePDF\PrintApplicationGuidePDF.vbproj]
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6112444Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6112753Z     8 Warning(s)
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6113066Z     0 Error(s)
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6113390Z 
2019-01-17T17:21:59.6114014Z Time Elapsed 00:00:37.73
2019-01-17T17:21:59.7031245Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
2019-01-17T17:21:59.7441685Z ##[section]Finishing: Build solution
```

thanks

Comment: If you can't post the build log, we can't help you.

Comment: The log is quite large.  I can post the whole thing, if that would help?  Right now, I added the end of the log.

Comment: The log clearly shows that `2019-01-17T17:21:59.6058362Z Build FAILED` (this is why MSBuild is returning 1). You need to look through the whole log to find a line containing "error", which will tell you exactly why it failed. Best thing to do would be to compare this log with a build log on your machine (where the build succeeds) to see at what stage the error creeps in.

Comment: Thank you.  I will add the full log.  But, every build says 0 errors.  There are some warnings, but that is all.

Comment: Never mind.  The post limits the number of characters.  The log is too long.  But, I have looked through the log.  there are no errors.  There are some warnings.  That is why I am having a hard time diagnosing the issue.

Comment: you could always upload it to somewhere like pastebin.com - but if you do this you should ensure there's nothing sensitive in the log. That's also why I suggested comparing it with the log from your local machine's successful build.

Comment: Do you have references that exist in the GAC or in the local program file tree? Check following threads if it give any help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404085/team-foundation-server-unable-to-build-missing-libraries-or-components  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483300/errors-using-gac-msil-assemblies-on-vsts

Comment: I dont know what the issue was.  I worked with our VSTS admin and they had me create a new branch, merge my code to that branch, and then I redeployed and it was fine (after they edited the build and release definitions)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I suggest you rebuild or even clean your solution and then rebuild or deploy your project.

After this action, if you still have this problem I thought maybe you could try the way in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491241/10383250).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.